# React create custom Hook that never rebuild

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook without a state and want to "persist" the hook.

The hook is called `useMessage()` and should only be rebuilt in the first render cycle since i don't use any state in there.

I want to have a global hook the redux hook `useDispatch()`.

How is that possible?

EDIT:

I just want to have 1 reference / a singelton of my hook to not get rerendered all the time! 
Is there any way to memorize the hook? My goal is that i am able to add the hook in dependencies of e.g. useEffect() and this never will cause a rerun of the useEffect(). Just like useDispatch / useRef / ...

Comment: Your question is unclear... What do you mean in "persist"? Do you mean that the hook shares the same value over the application?

Comment: the hook simply should not be rebuilt every time the "wrapper" component is. I want to be able to use the hook in most of my components without it gets rebuilt every time the state/parent changes

Comment: Like a React.memo or Callback for the hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is - you just can't. A custom hook will always rerun if the component where you included it runs again.

What I expected: Just return a memorized Value (`useMemo`) containing the dependencies in the array. This will keep the custom hook simple and only a small part will rerun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean - but try this:

```
const [myValue] = useState(() => myInitialValue);
```

useState accepts a callback function as a parameter, which will only be executed on first render for your component. For all future renders, it will return the first value that was returned from your function.